# Magento 2 Import Product Issue

Tags: magento2, import

I am using Magento 2.

During Product Import from csv each time stops at 68th or 69th row with following error.

Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s): 68

-product images are imported from url. like
   http://shoptrips.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/V11PRO-1134.jpg

- first 67th images names  include uppercase,- or numeric still imported fine. so it seems naming is not a problem.
- I changed my php.ini with 
    memory_limit 2048M
    max_execution_time: 36000
  still not worked.

Want to upload 300 rows at same time but only uploading first 68th and then gives error.

i am using godaddy server with 2GB memory

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MAGMI importer. its free and useful to import products - attributes - attribute-sets - associates - categories and more...

Comment: Your welcome @DaxitaPatel.